# is there a way to create draft invoice without any invoice items

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe is not allowing me to create an invoice if the customer does not have any pending invoice items. I have to create invoice items first and then create an invoice of all the pending invoice items of a customer. So, Is there a way to create a draft invoice first and then create its specific invoice items later?

Answer (score 0):

No, an invoice cannot be created without any invoice items. If you try to do so you'll get an error.

Comment: That's why we're here Paul.